# Connect to Kafka on Unix from Windows with Kerberos

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-producer-api

I'm quite new to Kafka so please bear with me. Here is my set up.
I have kafka hosted on a unix box. Clustered. and in a domain say B.
client is on windows. and am trying to connect to kafka hosted on B using a domain A. 
I have the keytab. and krb5. both these are set up in the envt. 
krb5.ini(and is set to envt variable KRB5_CONFIG)

```
 [logging]
 default = CONSOLE
 admin_server = CONSOLE
 kdc = CONSOLE

[libdefaults]
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 clockskew = 324000
 forwardable = true
 proxiable = true
 renewable = true
 default_realm = some.something.COM
  dns_lookup_realm = true
  dns_lookup_kdc = false
 default_tgs_enctypes = somethingelse
 default_tkt_enctypes = somethingelse

 [appdefaults]
   renewable = true

  [realms]
   some.something.COM = {
     kdc = some.something.COM
     admin_server = some.something.COM
 }
```

I also have set up Jaas.config(Kafka.client.ini in my case and is set to envt variable KAFKA_CLIENT_KERBEROS_PARAMS) below is the config

```
   KafkaClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="sample.keytab"
   storeKey=true
   useTicketCache=true
   serviceName="kafka"
   principal="svcacc@some.something.COM";
```

};

downloaded apache kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1.tgz and am executing this command.

```
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list <broker list> --topic <mytopic>    --security-protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

no matter what i change i keep getting below error

"security-protocol is not a recognised option"

can someone please help me in this?
i also added below props in producer.properties. but nothing seems to change. I'm not sure what i'm missing

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
```

I even tried setting this property in kafka-console-producer.bat but with no luck

```
set KAFKA_CLIENT_KERBEROS_PARAMS=- Djava.security.auth.login.config=..\..\config\kafka_Connection.ini
```

looking forward for your inputs. Many thanks (i've no control as of now on kafka server nor i will be able to explain why its hosted on domain B)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _"domain A"_ and _"domain B"_ >> are these different Active Directory "domains" i.e. different Kerberos "realms"? Or different network "domains" in the same Kerberos realm?

Comment: What do you mean by _"Kafka 2.12"_ >> is that the silly versioning used by Cloudera for its packaging of Apache Kafka 0.x?

Comment: sorry. yes., its different AD domains. i just corrected the version as well. it is  kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1.tgz

Comment: @Samson,in addition, the kafka server team while investigating did verify that they could execute above producer bat file using my keytab but on a linux box. it makes me wonder, i've done something wrong in my client setting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not too familiar with Kafka, and that error message does not clearly hint at a Kerberos problem.
But given that this is a cross-realm situation, you will ***probably*** hit a Kerberos snag sooner or later...

From Kerberos MIT documentation about `krb5.conf` section [**[capaths]**](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.15/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html?highlight=capath#capaths)

> In order to perform *direct* (non-hierarchical) cross-realm
>   authentication, **configuration is needed to determine the
>   authentication paths between realms**.
>
> A client will use this section to find the authentication path between
>   its realm and the realm of the server.

In other words, you get a Kerberos TGT (ticket-granting-ticket) for principal `wtf@USERS.CORP.DMN` but need a Kerberos service ticket for `kafka/brokerhost.some.where@SERVERS.CORP.DMN`. Each realm has its own KDC servers. Your Kerberos client *(the Java implementation in this case)* must have a way to "hop" from one domain to the others

---

***Scenario 1*** >> both realms are "brother" AD domains with mutual trust, and they use the default **hierarchical** relationship -- meaning that there is a "father" AD domain named `CORP.DMN` that is in the path from `USERS` to `SERVERS`.

Your `krb5.conf` should look like this...

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = USERS.CORP.DMN
kdc_timeout   = 3000
...

...

[realms]
USERS.CORP.DMN = {
  kdc = roundrobin.siteA.users.corp.dmn
  kdc = roundrobin.bcp.users.corp.dmn
}
SERVERS.CORP.DMN = {
  kdc = dc1.servers.corp.dmn
  kdc = dc2.servers.corp.dmn
  kdc = roundrobin.bcp.servers.corp.dmn
}
CORP.DMN = {
  kdc = roundrobin.corp.dmn
  kdc = roundrobin.bcp.corp.dmn
}
```

...assuming you have multiple AD Domain Controllers in each domain, sometimes behind DNS aliases doing round-robin assignment, plus another set of DC on a separate site for BCP/DRP. It could be more simple than that :-)

---

***Scenario 2*** >> there is trust enabled but the relationship does not use the default, hierarchical path.

In that case you must define explicitly that "path" in a `[capaths]` section, as explained in the Kerberos documentation.

---

***Scenario 3*** >> there is no trust between realms. You are screwed.

Or rather, you must obtain a different user that can authenticate on the same domain as the Kafka broker, e.g. `xyz@SERVERS.CORP.DMN`.
And maybe use a specific `krb5.conf` that states `default_realm = SERVERS.CORP.DMN` *(I've seen weird behaviors of some JDK versions on Windows, for example)*

---

Bottom line: you must require assistance from your AD administrators. Maybe they are not familiar with raw Kerberos conf, but they will know about the trust and about the "paths"; at this point it's just a matter of following the proper `krb5.conf` syntax.

Or, maybe, that conf has already been done by the Linux administrators; so you should require an example of their standard `krb5.conf` to check whether there is cross-domain stuff in there.

And of course you should enable **Kerberos debug traces** in your Kafka producer:

`-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true`
`-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

Just for the record, but not useful here... when using Keberos over HTTP (SPNego) there's an additional flag`-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true`

Comment: thank you Samson. your answer is much appreciated. i'm going to get some answers for all this. and try mysefl too. but i had one qn. our producer is coming from windows. so where do i set the krb5.debug to true?

Comment: please ignore my last qn. i just put it in envt variable. and it helped.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I had to change 2 things post your answer.  1. modify krb.ini to adher to second case of yours and modify kafka-run-class.bat to accept KAFKA_CLIENT_KERBEROS_PARAMS and voila worked like a charm. thank you again

Comment: to be fair, i re-posted my 3rd scenario qn in this link instead of editing above one. if you have further thoughts on it   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539925/net-kerberos-from-windows-to-linux-different-realms

Comment: @KaSh > I have no experience of the **.Net** implementation of Kerberos, so I can't help in the debugging...

Comment: I understand. should have been more clear. I think my issue is how to even connect based on kerberos from windows to linux. to make it worse completely diff realms

Comment: Java works on Windows, too... And nowadays, .Net works on Linux, too. It's not the OS that makes a difference, it's the framework, and its specific Kerberos implementation. Plus, on your other post, the error message does not really smell of a Kerberos issue. Some debug traces would be helpful.

Comment: Samson, just wondering if you would shed some light on how to set cpaths between untrusted domains. ? i have a diff svc account for kafka broker. say xyz@SERVERS.CORP.DMN.(as per your ex). but my client is in client@Client.CORP.DMN. there is one way trust. servers.corp.dmn trusts client.corp.dmn. would be quite appreciated. (i had to use java wrapper in .net to get things going for now. but back on this )

Comment: @KaSh > Honestly, no. I was lucky enough that I never had to set up a `[capaths]` configuration. The MIT documentation -- and Google -- are your only hope...

Comment: Thank you Samson. also for your prompt response. Let me get on with it. if i can get it working will post back here.