# .NET Kerberos from Windows to Linux (different realms)

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

Qn: 
If i've diff kerberos Realms, and the broker sits on Linux and producer sits on windows, how do enable the connectivity using Kerberos? I have valid keytab. and here is the krb5

Please see marked answer to this question in this link.

[Connect to Kafka on Unix from Windows with Kerberos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312403/connect-to-kafka-on-unix-from-windows-with-kerberos)

below question is continuation for 3rd scenario explained by @Samson.
answering some of Samson's suggestions, 
1 default realm is added in krb5. 
2.there is one way trust. the broker domain trusts my domain.

```
 [libdefaults]
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = false
 default_realm = SomeUrl.COM
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 udp_preference_limit = 1


 [domain_realm]

 .machine.test.group = SomeUrl.COM  
  machine.test.group = SomeUrl.COM

  [realms]
  SomeUrl.COM = {
  admin_server = SomeUrl.COM
  kdc = SomeUrl.COM
  }
```

SomeUrl.com is where the broker is placed.

here is the log from producer for this scenario.

producer connection to broker log: (I've edited the actual broker name and IP address)

> 7|2017-06-14 09:03:49.181|rdkafka#producer-1|BROKER| [thrd:app]:
>       sasl_plaintext:
>   //some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap: Added new broker with NodeId -1
>   7|2017-06-14 09:03:49.180|rdkafka#producer-1|BRKMAIN| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/int
>   ernal: Enter main broker thread
>   7|2017-06-14 09:03:49.227|rdkafka#producer-1|STATE| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/inter
>   nal: Broker changed state INIT -> UP
>   7|2017-06-14 09:03:49.229|rdkafka#producer-1|BRKMAIN| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.
>   test.group:9092/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
>   7|2017-06-14 09:03:49.230|rdkafka#producer-1|CONNECT| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.
>   test.group:9092/bootstrap: broker in state INIT connecting
>   rdkafka#producer-1 producing on KAFKA_MM_L0. q to exit.

When I try to send msgs (

> rdkafka#producer-1 producing on KAFKA_MM_L0. q to exit.
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.625|rdkafka#producer-1|CONNECT| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.
>   test.group:9092/bootstrap: Connecting to ipv4#1.1.1.1:9092 (sasl_plaintext) with socket 184
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.627|rdkafka#producer-1|STATE| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.te
>   st.group:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> CONNECT
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.637|rdkafka#producer-1|CONNECT| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.
>   test.group:9092/bootstrap: Connected to ipv4#1.1.1.1:9092
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.637|rdkafka#producer-1|CONNECTED| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machin
>   e.test.group:9092/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.638|rdkafka#producer-1|APIVERSION| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machi
>   ne.test.group:9092/bootstrap: Using (configuration fallback) 0.9.0 protocol features
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.640|rdkafka#producer-1|FEATURE| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.
>   test.group:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features to BrokerBalancedCo
>   nsumer,ThrottleTime,Sasl,BrokerGroupCoordinator,LZ4
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.643|rdkafka#producer-1|AUTH| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.tes
>   t.group:9092/bootstrap: Auth in state CONNECT (handshake not supported)
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.645|rdkafka#producer-1|STATE| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.te
>   st.group:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> AUTH
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.646|rdkafka#producer-1|SASL| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap: Initializing SASL client: service name kafka, hostname some.machine.test.group, mechanisms GSSAPI
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.665|rdkafka#producer-1|SASL| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap: Acquired Kerberos credentials handle (expiry in 2147483455.928712703s)
>   7|2017-06-14 09:04:33.676|rdkafka#producer-1|BROKERFAIL| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://some.machine.test.group:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://some.machi
>   ne.test.group:9092/bootstrap: **failed: err: Local: Authentication failure: (errno: Invalid argument)**